# How do I enable JPEG Support for PHP?

Tags: php, lamp, gd

My `Configure Command` doesn't say anything about jpg, nor gif/png, but I can see `gif/png support` in the output of `phpinfo()`.

I built PHP with `--with-gd`, but only `GIF Support` and `PNG Support` are in the output of phpinfo(), how do I enable `JPEG Support`?

**UPDATE**

I got this problem when compiling :

```
Sorry, I cannot run apxs.  Possible reasons follow:

1. Perl is not installed
2. apxs was not found. Try to pass the path using --with-apxs2=/path/to/apxs
3. Apache was not built using --enable-so (the apxs usage page is displayed)

The output of /usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs follows:
cannot open /usr/local/apache2/build/config_vars.mk: No such file or directory at /usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs line 218.
```

What should I do now?

Answer (score 1):

First cd to the directory of the PHP source. Then

```
make clean
```

Then compile with JPEG support (add this to all the other compile options you already had used):

```
--with-jpeg-dir=<put path to jpeg library here>
```

For example, if your jpeg library is located at:

```
/usr/lib/libjpeg.so
```

Use:

```
--with-jpeg-dir=/usr/lib
```

Comment: Is `make clean` necessary? I've compiled it many times before but never used it, but didn't met any problem yet.

Comment: It's not entirely necessary but good practice ;)

Comment: Oops,met this problem when I try to compile: ` cannot open /usr/local/apache2/build/config_vars.mk: No such file or directory at /usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs line 218. ` It used to work before...

Comment: What version of PHP are you trying to compile and install? What OS are you doing this on?

Comment: `PHP 5.2.8` and `Fedora release 10`. I pointed apxs2 by `--with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs` and this worked before..

Comment: It doesn't look like the apxs utility was installed in /usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs. Where did you install apache? /usr/local/apache2?

Comment: Yes, and I've verified apxs2 is in `/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs`

Comment: Hmmm. Did you install apache from source or using yum?

Comment: It's also installed from source.

Comment: Hmm, I suggest trying to recompile and reinstall apache making sure to pass the --enable-so option. Then once that's completed successfully retry compiling/installing php. It sounds like everything is in place, but something is amiss :(

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll wait several days to see if there is a solution without reinstalling everything, as it worked fine last time.